# where to place a regex express for validating an email address

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I found a post on github where someone provided a regex to fix the email validation but
there was no explanation of where it should be placed. It begins like this:

```
             "email": {
                 "alertText": "* Invalid Email Address"
             },
```

would someone please show me where I would place this?

Comment: never mind. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I know you figured it out but for the sake of others wanting to know

```
<input value="someone@nowhere.com" class="validate[custom[email]]" type="text" name="myEmail" id="myEmail" />
```

where "email" is the name of the validition you want to use. 
See [github repo docs](https://github.com/musicm122/jQuery-Validation-Engine)  for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my email rule:

```
"email": {
    // Shamelessly lifted from Scott Gonzalez via the Bassistance Validation plugin http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
    "regex": /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i,
    "alertText": "* Invalid email address"
},
```